# WPF Bind to Webbrowser element

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

First time posting here lurked for a while.

Recently I have started using WPF and am looking at adding a html editor to my application. Ideally I want to use ckEditor as I have used it for web things in the past. This is also a user control because I will be using it several places.

My question is is there anyway to bind a certain element of a webbrowser?

At the moment I have a one way binding to work - by forcing a script call to the webbrowser when the object changes

XAML:

```xml
<WebBrowser Name="editor" 
        Loaded="editor_Loaded" 
        Height="auto" 
        Width="auto"  
        src:WebBrowserHelper.Body="{Binding ElementName=notesUC, Path=MyHTML, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

c# behind the xaml

```cs
NotesUserControl.HtmlProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyHTML", typeof(string), typeof(NotesUserControl));
```

I have a Webbrowser helper control class, which allows me to actually make a binding to it which is :

```cs
public static class WebBrowserHelper
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BodyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Body", typeof(string), typeof(WebBrowserHelper), new PropertyMetadata(OnBodyChanged));

    public static string GetBody(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
    {
        return (string)dependencyObject.GetValue(BodyProperty);
    }

    public static void SetBody(DependencyObject dependencyObject, string body)
    {

        dependencyObject.SetValue(BodyProperty, body);

    }

    private static void OnBodyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser webBrowser = d as WebBrowser;
        if (webBrowser != null)
        {
            webBrowser.InvokeScript("set", e.NewValue as string ?? "&nbsp;");
        }
   }

}
```

Then Finally the implementation :

```xml
<uc:NotesUserControl x:Name="NotesControl"
                NoteLabel="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.name, ElementName=selectPanel, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                MyHTML="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.notes, ElementName=selectPanel, UpdateSourceTrigger=Property Changed}"
            />
```

HTML Page :

```xml
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Set the Data of the CkEditor
    function set(a)
    {
        // Get the editor instance that we want to interact with.
        var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.demo;
        //Sets the data to a
        editor.setData(a);
    }

    //Get the Data of the CK Editor
    function get()
    {
        var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.demo; 
        return editor.getData();
    }

</script>


<body>

    <textarea class="ckeditor" id="demo">
    </textarea>


</body>
```

I am sorry if this has been answered before or I have missed out information, been looking around for a couple of days now trying to find the answer but haven't.